# How can I alter Node.js network permissions in Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, networking, server, permissions, windows-10

So, I was setting up node js to develop with React. A little windows permissions pop-up came up and asked if I wanted to allow node.js to operate on public or local networks. Its default was public, but I changed it to local. I don't recall exactly what it said.

I feel that this may have something to do with my problem:
whenever I attempt to start my react app on localhost:3000, I get a connection time out. The start command for the node development server says that the app should be available at localhost:3000. I have tried two different react apps, both have this issue, which leads me to believe the issue is with node.

I used windows troubleshooter, it said:

> The device or resource (localhost) is not set up to accept connections
>   on port "3000".

I cannot find where to alter this permission in Windows 10, as it is baby-proofed. There is no "Advanced options" for me under apps and features.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a possible firewall blocking your Node.JS app, depending on a private or public network you're connected on. You might want your app to work on both networks, and you can do so by changing the options.

Try searching up 'Firewall and network protection" from your Windows 10 search bar and then go to "Allow an app through firewall" setting. It will open a separate window, where it shows if an app is enabled in "Private", "Public", or both, depending on what box is checkmarked. You can change these checkmarks to configure the networks for each app.

Edit: As suggested by another, I have added a [screenshot of the networks window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dkbL.png)

Comment: This answer is close but it will be better to attach some screenshots or add more clear conclusion to help understanding